# Seeing flash of inside panel before login page when user is not auth

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Whenever I enter my page, I have redirect to inside panel if user is logged in. I am checking here

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.authRequired)) {
    const { authState } = useAuthStore(router.pinia);
    if (authState == false) {
      return next('/login')
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

If user is not logged in, I am seeing a 0.5sec flash of `Panel` component, is there way to avoid this?

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Base",
    component: Base,
    redirect: "/",
    meta: {
      authRequired: true,
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        name: "Panel",
        component: Panel,
```